# Changing ownership of a folder and future subfolders

Tags: chown

I am running an ubuntu server.

Chown -R plex.plex /Folder just changes the permission of the current folder/subfolders/files. If i create a new folder it doesnt change the ownership to what i want. for example

```
chown -R plex.plex /media/plex_media
```

if i create a new folder inside plex_media. the new folder goes back to root. I need all future folders/files to be plex in that plex_media

Comment: Is your chmod command correct?

Comment: First what version of Ubuntu are you using? Second are you doing this logged in as the root user?

Answer (score 1):

when you create a directory, the directory will automatically be owned by the user you are using at that time.

for example you make a directory with root user, the the owner of directory is root.

Here are some ways that I recommend for you :

1. create new directory and change owner, i.e :

> mkdir new_dir && chmod -R flex:flex new_dir

2. create directory using flex user, from root you can login as flex user using command :

> sudo -u flex mkdir new_dir

hope this help

Comment: Wondering about the downvote as this is correct information. Any directory created by root will be owned by root. I would suggest changing the second option to `sudo -u flex mkdir new_dir` to keep it in one command.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Ihave update the answer  @doneal24

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what was the issue but deleted the folder and re created the folder as root and then used chown -R plex.plex /folder and everything is working as expected